# customize tinymce in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce, tinymce-rails

My `tinymce` is working fine with rails 4 but where do i customize the text_area.

I have added following block of code in `config/tinymce.yml`

```
theme_advanced_toolbar_location: top
theme_advanced_toolbar_align: left
theme_advanced_statusbar_location: bottom
theme_advanced_buttons3_add:
  - tablecontrols
  - fullscreen
plugins:
  - table
  - fullscreen
```

It i remove tinymce.yml file also it is working. Actually where do i customize it.

**Edit 1**

I followed [This link for installation](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of `tinymce-rails` are you using?  If it's v4.0 or later, the documentation on github is a little out of date for configuration.  Particularly tinymce doesn't come with an `advanced` theme now - it's called `modern` instead.  `config/tinymce.yml` is still the correct place to do the customisation, just some of the parameters have changed.

See [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) for the details on how to configure it.

Comment: Yes, and that's the link that is a little out-of-date for configuration.  Specifically `theme_advanced...` doesn't exist any more which is why removing it has no effect.  Follow the link in my answer and configure your `tinymce.yml` file using that.

Comment: Whether i have to place in `tinymce.yml` in `config` only

Comment: Configuration still goes in `config\tinymce.yml`.  For example, and you for you to check it's working, put `width: 500` and `height: 100` in your `tinymce.yml` and check you see a smaller editor.

Comment: In the tinymce.yml I have the following `toolbar : "bold italic underline alignleft aligncenter"` but how can i add `link(for url)` to the toolbar